# Can't keep a total of numbers in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that generate's random numbers in python. It is supposed to come up with two random numbers, add them. And then proceed to come up with two more random numbers and add them to the previous total. This is the code I used:

```
    import random
for x in range(1,10):
    if x == 1:
        int1 = random.randint(1,2)
        int2 = random.randint(1,2)
        total = int1 + int2
        print str(int1) + (' int1')
        print str(int2) + (' int2')    
        print str(total) + (' total')
    else:
        int1 = random.randint(1,2)
        int2 = random.randint(1,2)
        total = int1 + int2
        total = total + total
        print str(int1) + (' int1')
        print str(int2) + (' int2')    
        print str(total) + (' total')
```

Instead of adding the numbers to a running total I got this.

```
2 int1
1 int2
3 total
2 int1
1 int2
6 total
1 int1
2 int2
6 total
1 int1
2 int2
6 total
1 int1
1 int2
4 total
2 int1
1 int2
6 total
1 int1
1 int2
4 total
2 int1
1 int2
6 total
1 int1
2 int2
6 total
```

The first number is a random integer (called int1) and the second is another random integer (called int1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a line `total = 0` before the `for` loop. Also, the code you provided assigns `total` as the sum of the 2 random numbers generated instead of adding them to the previous value. `total = total + total` simply multiplies the variable `total` by 2.

```
import random
total = 0
for x in range(1,10):
    int1 = random.randint(1,2)
    int2 = random.randint(1,2)
    total = total + int1 + int2
    print str(int1) + (' int1')
    print str(int2) + (' int2')    
    print str(total) + (' total')
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite *total* in the *else* part with a new sum by this expression

```
total = int1 + int2
```

(that is why it "did not add"). As a better solution, take @timrau's

Answer (score 0):

In the else-branch which adds for the cases `x != 1` you overwrite the the previous `total`:

```
total = int1 + int2
total = total + total
```

which essentially means:

```
total = 2 * (int1 + int2)
```

This explains your output.

What you wanted is:

```
total = total + int1 + int2
```